# Getting the current user name or computer name in Extendscript

Tags: javascript, printing, extendscript, computer-name

I'm finally getting some headway made in my script for InDesign CS6.  Now, in order for it to know to which printer it should print a document, I need to query which computer the script is running on.  Barring that, perhaps the name of the currently logged-in user, which is really the same thing.  This is a Mac OS X environment, by the way.  Can anyone help or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen on [http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_$.html](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_%24.html), the `$.getenv()` method can be used to get any environment variable. On Windows you could use `$.getenv("COMPUTERNAME")`, and on Mac `$.getenv("HOSTNAME")` should work.

Let me know if this doesn't work. I don't have a Mac to test on, but there's probably other options.

**EDIT 1:** Are you using InDesign Server? If so, `app.serverHostName` and `app.serverSettings.hostName` would work.

**EDIT 2:** Here's another possible solution:

```js
var outputFile = new File(Folder.desktop.fsName + "/GetHostName.sh");
outputFile.open("w");
try {
    outputFile.write("scutil --get HostName > ~/Desktop/HostName.txt");
}
finally {
    outputFile.close();
}
outputFile.execute();

var inputFile = new File(Folder.desktop.fsName + "/HostName.txt");
inputFile.open("r");
try {
    var hostName = inputFile.read();
}
finally {
    inputFile.close();
}

$.writeln("Host Name: " + hostName);
```

The idea is to write a shell script to file and then execute it. The shell script gets the host name and writes it to a file. Then we open the file and read the host name.

Comment: I see where you're going with this, @dln385, but I'm afraid both `$.getenv();` and `$.getenv("HOSTNAME");` return `null`.  I'm going to see if there's a list of Mac OS X environment variables somewhere online.  And we're not using the Server flavor, just regular ol' InDesign CS6.

Comment: Playing with that `$.getenv()` method, I discovered `$.getenv("USER")` _does_ actually return the currently logged-in user, which should be good enough for my purposes.  If, however, you happen to discover the environment variable that Mac OS X 10.8 uses for the computer name as well, @dln385, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: See that.  That seems like an awful lot of code just to get the name of the computer on which the script is running.  Anyway, I think we'll stick with the `$.getenv("USER")` method for now.  Thanks for the help!